# what is wrong with my mongodb error 

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

this is my code:

```
for( var i = 1; i < 10; i++ ) db.things.save( { x:4, j:i } ); > db.things.find();
```

and the error is :

```
Wed Apr 27 10:45:16 SyntaxError: syntax error (shell):1
```

what is wrong with it  ,

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for( var i = 1; i < 10; i++ ) db.things.save( { x:4, j:i } ); > db.things.find();
                                                             ^--- missing
```

You're doing redirection, but you're not redirecting FROM anything. The previous statement has been terminated by the semi-colon.